# Why isn't the callback function called in IE ($.getJSON)?

Tags: jquery, callback, getjson

Why isn't the callback function called in IE?

1. A call to Flickr:

   ```
   $.getJSON("http://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photosets.getPhotos",
   {
       api_key: APIKey,    
       photoset_id: photoSetID,
       format: "json",
       per_page: 40,
       nojsoncallback: 1           
   }, displayImages);

   function displayImages(data) { alert('called'); }
   ```
2. A call to YouTube:

   ```
   $.getJSON('https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/username/favorites?alt=json', function(data)
   {
       alert('called');
   })
   ```

Both of these types of calls work on any other browser, except IE.
Can you please explain me why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery only supports cross-domain ajax in non-IE<=9 browsers. To use those APIs in IE, you need to use JSONp if available or add a [jQuery plugin](https://github.com/MoonScript/jQuery-ajaxTransport-XDomainRequest) that adds support for the XDomainRequest api used by IE.

If possible use JSONp; XDR has quite some limitations - see http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2010/05/13/xdomainrequest-restrictions-limitations-and-workarounds.aspx for details.

Comment: Oh, thank you, I didn't knew that. Just adding the plugin immediately solved the Flickr problem. The youtube one not yet, but I think it is fixable. Thank you again!